# Handling member authentication and access in Zend Framework App

Tags: zend-framework, authentication

I am working on porting a legacy PHP application to the Zend Framework. It is supposed to be a facebook application where the authentication is done via facebook. I have a question related to handling the member object once a member is authenticated.

Currently I am initializing a member class object in the Bootstrap.php and assigning that to an object in the Zend_Session. I then access the session wherever I need the member object for any processing (e.g. in a controller to call methods on the member model and assign the data returned to the view object)

Is this a recommended way to do things? If not, I'd be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Satyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, one would use `Zend_Auth` and an authentication adapter to store your member object in the session storage of the `Zend_Auth` singleton which you could check/access via (in a controller, say):

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($auth->hasIdentity()){
    $member = $auth->getIdentity();
    $this->view->name = $member->getName(); 
}
```

The authentication process itself involves creating an authentication adapter `$adapter`, populating it with the credentials provided by the user, and checking the result of:

```
Zend_Auth::authenticate($adapter);
```

More details in the [Zend_Auth docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html).

Also, note that if you have some module or controller that requires login for access, you could place this checking code in a [front-controller plugin](http://devzone.zend.com/1224/front-controller-plugins-in-zend-framework/) with a `routeShutdown($request)` hook. If the request is for a protected controller and the user is not logged-in, then redirect to the login page. Just register the plugin during boootstrap.

Comment: Thank you! This helped, although I won't get a chance to implement this. I have documented it so that the student group that takes over after me can use the zend framework more extensively.